# How to append input box value between scopes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was reading this example http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/3/ in this example once you click on **add  to list** it added your entered data in **Unchecked:** array below with **check item** button and when you press check item button it pushes the values in **Checked item** array. This is very simple example. What I am going to trying is I have added new input text box in **Unchecked:** array and trying to send their value to the **Checked item** array but it is not updating. My working demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/240/

**Controller:**

```
// Add a Item to the list
$scope.addItem = function () {

    $scope.items.push({
        amount: $scope.itemAmount,
        name: $scope.itemName,
        //This one I have added
        qty: $scope.qty
    })
```

**HTML:**

```
     <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="item-unchecked">
            <td><b>amount:</b> {{item.amount}} -</td>
            <td><b>name:</b> {{item.name}} -</td>
             /*This is one I have added*/
            <td><b>qty:</b> <input type="number" ng-model="qty" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
        <button ng-click="toggleChecked($index)">check item</button>
```

I am just attempting but don't know the correct way of doing this. Please any one can help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any `qty` stuff in that fiddle, and it's not really clear to me what "it is not updating" means.

Comment: Not updating means once enter any value in the input box which I had added in the Unchecked array it should added in the Checked array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made some changes to your code (added qty filed to the model) . now its working .

But the main reason it was not working was - since this line :

```
<button ng-click="toggleChecked($index)">check item</button>
```

was outside of ng-repeat, toggleChecked($index) doesn't get the index value .

here is the updated script : http://jsfiddle.net/7n8NR/242/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rabi. Can you share js fiddle url I am not able to see the changes.

Comment: Looks great but I don't want to repeat the check item button that's why I had kept outside the table. Is there any way that button should not repeat. Thanks.